# how to add condition which check xml data with lookup table

Tags: xslt

I want to ask. there is posible to add condition which will be checking xml data with lookup table, and if  we didnt't have value in lookup table add const 8 to output?
xslt Code:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:key name="Department" match="Department" use="../Collection"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">
    <document>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </document>
</xsl:template>
 <xsl:template match="line">
     <xsl:variable name="inputDep" select="field[@id='3']"/>
<Department>
    <xsl:for-each select="document('lookup.xml')">
        <xsl:for-each select="key('Deparment',$inputDep)">
            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:for-each>
</Department>

 </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

lookup table:

```
<document>
    <line-item>
        <Collection>1</Collection>
        <Department>3</Department>
    </line-item>
    <line-item>
        <Collection>2</Collection>
        <Department>1</Department>
    </line-item>
    <line-item>
        <Collection>3</Collection>
        <Department>2</Department>
    </line-item>
</document>
```

xml file:

```
<document>
    <line id="0">
        <field id="3"><![CDATA[1]]></field>
    </line>
    <line id="1">
        <field id="3"/>
    </line>
    <line id="2">
        <field id="3"/><![CDATA[4]]></field>
    </line>
</document>
```

result:

```
<Department>3<Department>
<Department>8<Department>
<Department>8<Department>
```

Comment: Why the inner for-each loop? Do you expect that the lookup using the Deparment (sic) key will return more than one node? Will the output be correct if it does?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could assign the looked-up value to a variable and choose what to output based on whether anything was found.

*Edit 2:* A full demonstration stylesheet:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

  <xsl:key name="Department" match="Department" use="../Collection"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <document>
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </document>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="line">
    <xsl:variable name="inputDep" select="field[@id='3']"/>
    <Department>
      <xsl:for-each select="document('lookup.xml')">
        <xsl:variable name="value" select="key('Department',$inputDep)"/>
        <xsl:choose>
          <xsl:when test="$value">
            <xsl:value-of select="$value"/> <!-- see note -->
          </xsl:when>
          <xsl:otherwise>8</xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </Department>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Note: Replaced the `xsl:for-each` loop in the original stylesheet with a simple `xsl:value-of`, assuming that the looping the values was not intentional. If it actually was, you can replace this with a for-each loop.

Comment: inner for each for lookup table not for xml file. I try to use your answer but it doesn't work.. I try to add your code instead of for each loop.

Comment: @Petras, tried to clarify my answer by providing a more complete example code illustrating what I had in mind.

Comment: I try your's solution, first of all show me error on <xsl:variable name="inputDep" select="field[@id='3']"/> line. I try to change select value to /field[@id=3], but then all department=8

Comment: @Petras, what error message do you get? That part is directly from your own example code.

Comment: Unknown Named key. I tried to proceed this code on altova 2011 rel.2

Comment: @Petras, check the spelling of the key name. In your `key()` function call (which I copied verbatim) you have 'Deparment', but in your `xsl:key` definition that you added later to your example code, you have 'Department'.

Comment: i renamed key department to Department1. it's not helped. errors the same.

Comment: Edit 2: Provided a complete stylesheet and fixed the Department/Deparment misspelling. It works for me.

Comment: now it's working. I don't know why it doesn't work on my pc earlier. thanks for answer.